# Runtime exception raised binding a click event in JScript

Tags: jscript

The following code snippet gives me the following exception

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.JScript.JScriptException: Function expected

Stack Trace is

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.JScript.JScriptException: Function expected
>      at Microsoft.JScript.LateBinding.Call(Binder binder, Object[] arguments, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParameters, Boolean construct, Boolean brackets, VsaEngine engine)
>      at Microsoft.JScript.LateBinding.Call(Object[] arguments, Boolean construct, Boolean brackets, VsaEngine engine)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
>      at MForms.ScriptManagerM3.RunScript(Type scriptType, ControlScript controlScript, Object runContext, IScriptDebugOutput scriptDebugOutput)
>      at Mango.UI.Script.ScriptToolControl.Run()

The code snippet is

```
import System;
import System.Windows;
import System.Windows.Controls;
import MForms;
import Mango.UI;
import Mango.UI.Core;
import Mango.UI.Core.Util;
import Mango.UI.Services;
import System.Collections.Generic;
import System.Collections;

package MForms.JScript {
    class ValidateField {
        var controller;
        var debug;
        var value;
        var textBoxlotref1Element;
        var max;
        var min;

        public function Init(element : Object, args : Object, controller : Object, debug : Object) {
            var content : Object = controller.RenderEngine.Content;
            this.textBoxlotref1Element =ScriptUtil.FindChild(content, "WLBREF");

            textBoxlotref1Element.add_Click(testMethod);
        }

        public function testMethod(sender: Object, e: EventArgs) {

        }
    }
}
```

I am a newbie to JScript. I think I am missing a simple step somewhere.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching this.

```
function ButtonEventHandler1(sender, e : EventArgs)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Event is Fired!");
}
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work. The runtime exception is thrown before event is fired. Even before the click event is attached.